# combining Month Name with the Day SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have this code here and I need to get combine the Name of Month and the Day

```
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, GETDATE()) AS NameOfMonth,
       DATEPART(DAY, TIMESTAMP) AS DateDay,
       AVG(CAST(REPLACE(roundtrip, 'ms', '') AS NUMERIC(30, 2))) AS DailyDuration
FROM (
    SELECT TIMESTAMP,
           roundtrip
    FROM tblServer_Status
    WHERE MONTH(TIMESTAMP) = MONTH(DATEADD(dd, -1, GETDATE()))
        AND YEAR(TIMESTAMP) = YEAR(DATEADD(dd, -1, GETDATE()))
        AND DATEPART(HOUR, TIMESTAMP) BETWEEN 0 AND 23
        AND server = 'WSMV217'
        AND site_code = 'MK'
) AS Calls
GROUP BY DATEPART(DAY, TIMESTAMP)
ORDER BY DATEPART(DAY, TIMESTAMP)
```

And the output of that code is like this

```
| Name of Month | Date Day | Daily Duration |
     January         1            351
     January         2            351
     January         3            351
     January         4            351
     January         5            351
     January         6            351
     January         7            351
```

And I need to combine the name and the day like this:

```
| Name of Month/Date Day | Daily Duration |
     January  1                 351
     January  2                 351
     January  3                 351
     January  4                 351
     January  5                 351
     January  6                 351
     January  7                 351
```

Can any one help me. I know this is a simple codes but I swear. I didn't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
SELECT (DATENAME(month,getdate()) + ' ' + CAST(DATEPART(day,timestamp) as varchar(5))) AS [Name of Month/Date Day], 
AVG(CAST(REPLACE(roundtrip, 'ms', '') AS NUMERIC (30,2))) AS DailyDuration
FROM 
(SELECT timestamp, roundtrip 
     FROM tblServer_Status 
     WHERE Month(timestamp) = Month(DateAdd(dd, -1, GetDate())) 
     And Year(timestamp) = Year(DateAdd(dd, -1, GetDate())) 
     And DATEPART(hour, timestamp) BETWEEN 0 AND 23 and server = 'WSMV217' 
     And site_code = 'MK') AS Calls
GROUP BY DATEPART(day, timestamp)
ORDER BY DATEPART(day, timestamp)
```